# Problem with sound

Tags: sound, kubuntu

guys! I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 (KDE PLASMA 5) and I have next problem: when I turn on my laptop, my loudspeakers don't working. They are working, when I reconnected jack 3.5mm.
What change I need to make in settings? Thanks.